# I'm getting duplicated print Job on windows 7 client machine for shared printer

Tags: windows-7, printing, notifications, network-printers, print-spooler-api

I'm having a pb with print Jobs for shared printer

I' have a printer shared on win server 2008

And I'm using this printer from windows 7 client machine

I'm developping an application that writes all printer notifications for all print Jobs

And for only one job in the print queue, i'm receiving the notification of two job with two different JobID and two différent machine name.

My question is why Two Jobs are  created for only one job sent to the print Queue? and why they are so different? the virtual job have the machine name of le client and the real job have the machine name of print server

Comment: You need to provide more information like what API's you are using, some code, for someone to help you

Comment: API windows : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162861(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: EnumPrinters, OpenPrinter, FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification, WaitForMultipleObjects, WaitForSingleObject, FindNextPrinterChangeNotification : that's is my call sequence of windows functions

Comment: For the notification criteria, are you using PRINTER_CHANGE_ALL ?

Comment: yes, I pass it(PRINTER_CHANGE_ALL )  as third param for FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification and the fourth param of FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification is an instance of PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS struct = NotificationOptions = {2,PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS_REFRESH, 2,Notifications /* What we want notifications of */ };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification generates a notification when an application on the client machine fires a job, and is added to the client spooler queue. When the client spooler queue forwards the print job to the print server, another notification is generated. You can try using PRINTER_CHANGE_SERVER instead of PRINTER_CHANGE_ALL, and see if still 2 notifications are generated.

Comment: I'will try this and I'l be back

Comment: thanks stamhaney, but this flag (PRINTER_CHANGE_SERVER) is to use with à handle on server not on printer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541661.aspx )

Comment: ok. I guess then probably picking up the relevant pieces of information from both the notifications and using it as you find it appropriate, would be the only option

Comment: Thanks a lot Stam  for this tip. with this flag and with a handle on server I'm not receiving the virtual job any more. But it causes pb with Ip Printers

Comment: I' juste unchecked "render Print Jobs on client computer" and the virtual job disapear. But with the notificaiton of real job, I'm not getting the right information about PrintedPage an totalPages and even status is Not Ok, I'm tracing all data I'm receiving fro notifications and I'm not seing the correct values? have u any Idea about that? how to get the correct value (it sems like I haven't enough notifications? )

Comment: PRINTER_CHANGE_SERVER works only with windows 7& 8 and windows server 2008.

Comment: I can suggest you to check the notifications [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162723(v=vs.85).aspx), to verify that you are not missing any notifications you want to capture. You are right about PRINTER_CHANGE_SERVER supported on Windows 7 & Windows Sever 2008